# "network" location provider requires ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission in GPS Location App

Tags: android, gps, location

I have a problem with my GPS Location App I have tried by all means and I can't find the solution (I'm developing in Android 6.0) , this is the problem:

```
"network" location provider requires ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission
```

this is my XML FIle:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".chooseEmergency"></activity>
</application>
```

And this is my LocationManager Code:

```
    LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Localizacion Local = new Localizacion();
    Local.setMainActivity(this);
    mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
            (LocationListener) Local);

   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        //use checkSelfPermission()
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
    } else {
        //simply use the required feature
        //as the user has already granted permission to them during installation
    }
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 1);

    public class Localizacion implements LocationListener {
    MainActivity mainActivity;

    public MainActivity getMainActivity() {
        return mainActivity;
    }

    public void setMainActivity(MainActivity mainActivity) {
        this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {


        latitud = loc.getLatitude();
        longitud = loc.getLongitude();

        this.mainActivity.setLocation(loc);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {//pndiente de escribir;
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {//pendiente
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

}
```

Please help, I took 2 days looking at internet solutions and nothing works for me

Comment: Just a random suggestion, check app's granted permission in settings.

Comment: That code will not compile. Make sure that you are requesting permission, and actually getting it, before attempting to use `LocationManager`.

Comment: But I dont know what's the right way I tried a lot of solutions and anyone works for me :(